# Segmentation fault due to large buffer size when reading a large line in C

Tags: c, csv, fgets, mmap

The CSV files that need to be read are quite large, but each of them only has only one line (from kb to gb), one large line. I tried to use the code below, but the maximum size can be only reached by `1000000`, adds one more `0` resulted `Segmentation fault`. I read that the buffer has a limitation, but is there another way just to read that one large line and put then in an int array? or do I really need to use `mmap`? Thanks a lot!

```
struct IntArrLen {
 int length;
 int max_index;
 int* arr;
};


struct IntArrLen readInt(char* str){
    struct IntArrLen intArr;
    intArr.length = 0;
    intArr.arr = NULL;

    char file_name[100];
    strcat(file_name, str);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!fp){
        return intArr;
    }

    char* token = NULL;
    // define the maximum size of line
    int max_size = 1000000;
    char row_content[max_size];
    int* arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * max_size);
    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", row_content);

    int count = 0;
    token = strtok(row_content, ",");
    while(token != NULL){
        arr[count] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        count ++;
    }

    intArr.length = count;
    intArr.arr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * intArr.length);
    memcpy(intArr.arr, arr, sizeof(int) * intArr.length);

    free(arr);
    return intArr;
}
```

the CSV file is something like this:

```
1245,2234532,23243523,235235325,325362436,5473658658,65879659,....
```

Comment: Post a [mcve], please

Comment: why won't you `malloc` the `row_content` ? It can indeed cause the segfault as it is allocated on stack.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]", row_content);` --> `fscanf(fp, "%999999[^\n]", row_content);` to avoid UB.  Consider `fgets()` instead.  In either case, check return value.

Comment: It's literally the name of the website...

Comment: If each of the CSV files has just one line with numbers separated by commas, why don't you simply `fscanf(fp, "%d,", arr + count)` them value by value? You can look at a file as a stream, you don't need to read its contents as a whole.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah! You are right, thanks a lot!

Comment: @anastaciu  Now I get it lol

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sorry but what is UB?

Comment: @thebusybee does it work more efficient in this way?

Comment: What is "efficiency" in this case? The underlying system buffers the file's contents in blocks while reading, but your program does not need the (up to GBs, as you wrote) memory to store the complete file. I'd expect no time penalty, but a much smaller memory footprint.

Comment: @ErwinZangwill [undefined behavior (UB)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14487077/2410359) means the rest of code is questionable.